# Having problems with a simple if/then statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a designer and not very skilled at coding anything but HTML/CSS. I barely understand Javascript but I can usually Franken-copypasta my way to a successful jQuery script for simple animations and basic functionality. In this case though, I'm getting tripped up somewhere and I have no idea where.

The script is simply intended to toggle the "left" property of the "#left-sidebar" element between 0 and -250px when the "#showNav" button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var navPos = $('#left-sidebar').position().left;
$('#showNav').click(function(){
    if(navPos = -250){
        $('#left-sidebar').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('#left-sidebar').animate({
            left: '-250px'
        }, 500);
    }
});
});
```

I figured I could write an if/then statement to check if the element was already at -250 or not, and switch to the opposite value accordingly. Currently, clicking the button causes the #left-sidebar to go from -250 to 0, but when I click the button again, it doesn't return to -250 as expected. I imagine this is a pretty simple fix, but I don't even know where to start...

Comment: You have a syntax error, should be: `navPos == -250` because is a comparison _not_ an assignment.

Comment: Also you should put `var navPos = $('#left-sidebar').position().left;` in your click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Move `var navPos = $('#left-sidebar').position().left;` inside of your click handler and it will work.

Right now, you are assigning `navPos` only once. So `navPos` always will hold the initial value, regardless of how often you click.

So what you need is the position at the time when the user clicks on the `#showNav` div.

This is the complete, updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showNav').click(function(){
    var navPos = $('#left-sidebar').position().left; 

    if(navPos == -250){
      $('#left-sidebar').animate({left: '0px'}, 500);
    } else {
      $('#left-sidebar').animate({left: '-250px'}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I've updated the code. Still no dice though... it pops out but won't pop back in.

Comment: you probably copied the wrong if condition, I copied if(navPos = -250) from your question. This can't work. Updated my answer to if(navPos == -250)

Comment: This definitely works—my mistake. I had manually moved the var declaration into the click function instead of copying/pasting the code. I hadn't fixed the "=" symbol in the if statement. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**[CODE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ujitas/1/edit)**

```
$(function(){ // a bit shorter DOM ready

    $('#showNav').click(function(){
        var navPos = $('#left-sidebar').position().left;       
        $('#left-sidebar').stop().animate({left: navPos===-250 ? 0 : -250}, 500);
    });

});
```

- on click retrieve the position and
- with a simple *Ternary operator* that just says:

```
is navPos === -250            ?
if YES (animate left to 0   ) :
if NO  (animate left to -250) ;
```